PyTorch Cholesky Decomposition Fails on GPU but Works on CPU for same matrix
I'm encountering an issue with Cholesky decomposition in PyTorch when running on a GPU. The following code works perfectly on the CPU:
import torch
device = torch.device('cpu')
torch.manual_seed(1)
size = 4096
F = torch.rand(int(size / 2), int(size / 2)).to(device)
F = torch.matmul(F, F.T)
torch.linalg.cholesky(F)

However, when I move the matrix to the GPU, I get an error:
import torch
device = torch.device('cuda')
torch.manual_seed(1)
size = 4096
F = torch.rand(int(size / 2), int(size / 2)).to(device)
F = torch.matmul(F, F.T)
torch.linalg.cholesky(F)

The error message is:
    torch.linalg.cholesky(F)
torch._C._LinAlgError: linalg.cholesky: The factorization could not be completed because the input is not positive-definite (the leading minor of order 2044 is not positive-definite).

Why does this happen? How can I resolve this issue?
PS:
PyTorch version: 2.3.0
CUDA version: 12.1

Not much makes sense here — you state you are using “the same matrix”, but that can’t be true if you use an randomly populated matrix which will be different each time you run the code. Then you claim that the GPU version is returning an error. But the error you shown is plainly being produced by numpy.linalg.cholesky, which is a CPU function.

@talonmies torch.manual_seed(1) I set the random seed. Then everytime I run the script, the matrix will be same. You can check the matrix in small size, e.g. 2x2.

It's a numerical precision issue. Note that if I calculate the eigenvalues of F, I get negative values, meaning your matrix is not PSD:
import torch
device = torch.device('cuda')
torch.manual_seed(1)
size = 4096
F = torch.rand(int(size / 2), int(size / 2)).to(device)
F = torch.matmul(F, F.T)
eigvals, _ = torch.linalg.eig(F)
print(eigvals.real.min())


On my machine, the value is -0.000232202626648359
Obviously, mathematically F @ F.T is a PSD matrix. So, I suggest you generate your matrix more robustly, like this:
import torch
device = torch.device('cuda')
torch.manual_seed(1)
size = 4096


def generate_psd_matrix(size, min_condition_number = 0.01, max_condition_number = 100):
    A = torch.randn(size, size)
    Q, _ = torch.linalg.qr(A)
    singular_values = torch.FloatTensor(size).uniform_(min_condition_number, max_condition_number)
    D = torch.diag(singular_values)
    return Q @ D @ Q.T


F = generate_psd_matrix(size)
u, s, v = torch.svd(F)
condition_number = s.max().item() / s.min().item()
print("Condition number:", condition_number)
L = torch.linalg.cholesky(F)
print(L)


